# How do I push a PowerShell script out to domain computers?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to run a command that will add a local administrator onto computers. However, I am struggling to combine it with a script to push this out to all domain computers under a particular OU in Active Directory.

Below is the first bit of script is the command I'm using to create the user.

I also have a script to pull all the required OU computers into a CSV, but I need to then push the below script to the PCs in this CSV. Is this possible? 
I only want it to run the once, not as a start up script as I don't want it to create multiple users.

```
$Username = "user"
$Password = "Password"
$group = "Administrators"
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$existing = $adsi.Children | where {
    $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' -and $_.Name -eq $Username
}

if ($existing -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Creating new local user $Username."
    & NET USER $Username $Password /add /y /expires:never

    Write-Host "Adding local user $Username to $group."
    & NET LOCALGROUP $group $Username /add
}

Write-Host "Ensuring password for $Username never expires."
& WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='$Username'" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
```

Comment: I'd use Group Policy to do this: [group-policy-creating-a-standard-local-admin-account](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/12/10/group-policy-creating-a-standard-local-admin-account/)

Comment: Does this way create a proper local admin that is not associated with the domain? So if the PC was to be removed from the domain we could still log onto it using this local admin account

Comment: You can set your local admins on the machine using Group Policy as well.

Comment: I don't believe that extension works any more because setting a password in a GPO is not secure.

Comment: Would LAPS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/mt227395.aspx) possibly work better? It has workstations manage the built-in local administrator account password (even if the built-in account is renamed to something else). Has a known deployment methodology, avoids having admin creds in a script, uses a unique password for each machine so compromising one box doesn't provide access to others, and allows admins to get the account password when needed (I've set up self-service portals where user could get pwd for *their* computer too, but that depends on having a user=>computer mapping).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to run your script only once on each computer, all of the computers are powered on and PowerShell remoting is activated, you could do it like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=mydomain,DC=tld" | foreach {

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.DNSHostname -ScriptBlock {

        # Your script goes here...
    }
}
```

The example above reads all computer objects from a predefined OU from Active Directory, connects to every one and executes your script (or anything in the `-Scriptblock {}` ) on the computer.